# Prevent an es6 default export from being imported

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I have a small node package that I would like users to only used named imports in their project.

`import { Logger } from 'logger';`

However, there is nothing stopping the user from doing

`import defaultImportedLogger from 'logger';`

They will just learn the hard way when they find out that `defaultImportedLogger` is `undefined` because my project doesn't have an `export default` anywhere. Hence the default export is `undefined`.

If I try to import a named exports such as:

`import { foo } from 'logger'`

my editor will complain because `foo` isn't exposed. Why doesn't my editor complain in the default import situation?

Comment: Not exporting something will prevent them from importing it (but not from trying to, nothing can do that). You're just doing the right thing.

Comment: "*Why doesn't my editor complain?*" - that's a separate question.

Comment: Correct @Bergi. For those that are curious about the editor question, this [eslint rule](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/default.md#rule-details) should help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of trying to import the default export when it wasn't defined depends on which bundler you're using. For example Rollup [throws an error](https://rollupjs.org/repl?version=0.58.2&shareable=JTdCJTIybW9kdWxlcyUyMiUzQSU1QiU3QiUyMm5hbWUlMjIlM0ElMjJtYWluLmpzJTIyJTJDJTIyY29kZSUyMiUzQSUyMmltcG9ydCUyMHRlc3QlMjBmcm9tJTIwJy4lMkZ0ZXN0LmpzJyUzQiU1Q24lNUNudGVzdCgpJTNCJTVDbiUyMiU3RCUyQyU3QiUyMm5hbWUlMjIlM0ElMjJ0ZXN0LmpzJTIyJTJDJTIyY29kZSUyMiUzQSUyMiUyMiU3RCU1RCUyQyUyMm9wdGlvbnMlMjIlM0ElN0IlMjJmb3JtYXQlMjIlM0ElMjJjanMlMjIlMkMlMjJuYW1lJTIyJTNBJTIybXlCdW5kbGUlMjIlMkMlMjJnbG9iYWxzJTIyJTNBJTdCJTdEJTJDJTIyYW1kJTIyJTNBJTdCJTIyaWQlMjIlM0ElMjIlMjIlN0QlN0QlMkMlMjJleGFtcGxlJTIyJTNBbnVsbCU3RA==): "'default' is not exported by <filename>".

I don't think there's any way to prevent users from importing the default export. The best you can do is export a function which throws an error when called, with error message "Don't use the default export".

Comment: I would consider every bundler that doesn't detect this to be buggy. The spec defines that non-resolved imports must throw. And no, you should *not* export a function that throws, as that would make the compile time check impossible. You'd get the runtime exception anyway.

Comment: @Bergi Well, I think it's better to get an error message with an explanation what went wrong than just `undefined`.

Comment: I would guess the exception "*`_logger.default` is not a function*" or similar should be helpful enough, though of course that depends on the transpiler. I don't see what makes the `default` import special, you can't and shouldn't provide an extra error message for every possible export that does not exist.